# change csv file variable from bytes to string in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which I get from the frontend so I have it stored in a variable. Now I want to use the csv reader from the csv python library. This is my code:

```
def parseCSV(file):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

But this isn't working because every line of the file is byte format and not string. How can I change the entire file variable from byte to string and make the code work?

I've already seen some solutions for this problem if I read a csv file from a folder and open it with `with open ("file.csv", "r")`. But I can't read this csv file from a folder so I somehow need to change byte to string.

I've already tried something like this but this is not working:

```
def parseCSV(file):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line.decode("utf-8") in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a solution for this problem.
I just had to change the following line:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
```

to this line:

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(file, 'utf-8'))
```

and import codecs as `import codecs`

So if anyone else should have the same problem this should make the code work.